# Who am I in this Rebus Puzzle?

Tags: rebus

[image]

Who am I? This one should go pretty quick. For more info see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus

Comment: +1 because I love Star Wars; but I got it instantly!

Comment: I did say it was an easy one :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> "O + bee + wand - d;  Can + O + bee" =
>  = **"Obi-Wan Kenobi"** (Jedi Knight of Star Wars fame)

Comment: I'm 9 minutes too late :(